# Make a $2$ unit bottle from $4$ and $3$ unit bottles

Tags: algorithms

Assume that we have only two bottles. The first one's volume is $3$ units and the second one's volume is $4$ units.  We can perform $3$ kinds of operations :

> 1. Fill an empty bottle with water.
> 2. Empty a full bottle.
> 3. Pouring the contents of one bottle into the other one.

How can we reach a bottle with $2$ units of volume watter inside it?

Comment: Is one allowed to use some other unmarked vessel or not?

Comment: @TheCount obviously, the answer is no

Comment: No, Tina, it is not at all obvious, because you did not say one way or the other. "An empty bottle" or "A full one" do not specify only the two in the problem.

Comment: @TheCount ok, i added the word "only" :) is it right now ?

Comment: It wasn't 'wrong' before, but I was asking because it wasn't clear to me, and it opens up tons of other ways to do the problem. I took offense at you saying "obviously". But it is no matter. You have a nice solution below and all is well. Best.

Comment: @TheCount thanks for your attention :)

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill $3$ units bottle
pout its water to $4$ units bottle
Fill $3$ units bottle again
pout its water to $4$ units bottle till it gets full.
remaining water in the  $3$ units bottle is $2$ litre

Comment: Thanks ... But how did you manage to solve this problem so fast and easily? I want to know the algorithm ...

Comment: [Here's a good video](https://youtu.be/0Oef3MHYEC0) explaining how to solve these sorts of problems.

Comment: honestly i don't know how i approached this problem. was thinking to various possibilities and accidentally came across this solution.

Comment: You always want to pour in one direction.  Just keep doing it until you get where you want to go or until you repeat a previous state.  If you repeat a previous state you can report the task is impossible.  Here you could also fill 4, pour into 3, empty 3, pour 1 into 3, fill 4, pour 2 into 3, leaving 2 in the 4.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this kind of problem is generally similar.
Given $a$ and $b$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$ we can apply Bezout to find $(u,v)$ such that $au+bv=1$.

In fact here $1$ (1 liter) is not interesting, but similarly there exists $(u,v)$ such that $au+bv=2$.

Here $4*(+2)+3*(-2) = 8-6=2$, the signs are also of interest:

- $+$ indicates the recipient which is filled
- $-$ the recipient which is emptied (this is also the one we pour into).

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
action & \text{4 lit.} & \text{3 lit.} \\
\hline
 & 0 & 0  \\
fill & 4 & 0 & + \\
pour & 1 & 3 \\
empty & 1 & 0 & - \\
pour & 0 & 1 \\
fill & 4 & 1 & +\\
pour & 2 & 3 \\
empty & 2 & 0 & - 
\end{array}

So you see we filled twice the 4 liters bottle and emptied twice the 3 liters bottle to finally get $2l$ in the 4 liters bottle.

Let's examine another situation: bottle of 7 liters and 11 liters and I want 6 liters.

Here $7*(+4)+11*(-2)=28-22=6$, the signs indicate we are filling the 7 liters bottle 4 times and we pour in the 11 liters bottle and empty it 2 times. Let's go...

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
action & \text{7 lit.} & \text{11 lit.} \\
\hline
 & 0 & 0  \\
fill & 7 & 0 & + \\
pour & 0 & 7 \\
fill & 7 & 7 & + \\
pour & 3 & 11 \\
empty & 3 & 0 & - \\
pour & 0 & 3 \\ 
fill & 7 & 3 & + \\ 
pour & 0 & 10 \\ 
fill & 7 & 10 & + \\ 
pour & 6 & 11  \\
empty & 6 & 0 & -
\end{array}

So next time you have a problem with two bottles of contenance $a,b$ and you want $c$, try to find first the equation $au+bv=c$. In general it can be found by hand quite quickly.